# trace Inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products, trace

[Attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hhPY.jpg) I have come across this sequence of questions whilst revising for my linear algebra exam,I have tried to answer these questions (with my attempt attached) but I am in no way sure that I have got it right. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

(a) Let  be the vector space of 3×3 real symmetric matrices (i.e. matrices which satisfy  transpose =). Show that ⟨,⟩:→ℝ given by ⟨,⟩=Tr() is an inner product on

(b) Consider the following matrices in : =[(1,0,1),(0,1,0),(1,0,0)] and =[(1,0,1),(0,−3,0),(1,0,0)]
Find a matrix that is orthogonal to both  and  with respect to the inner product.

Comment: You may want to type your attempt instead of posting it as an image. See [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) for some help.

Answer (score 1):

To show that $<,>$ is a inner porduct,

You just have to show that $<,>$ is a bilinear symetric definite positive form.

For the second question you don't have to compute the eigen values of A or B.

You must find $C \in V$ such that $Tr(AC)=Tr(BC)=0$

You have to write what it means with $A,B,C$ coefficient, then you will find  some conditions on the coefficients of $C$ in order to have $C$ orthogonal to $A$ and $B$

Comment: Thing is I don’t understand how I’m meant to prove linearity, symmetry or positive definiteness just off of that information alone

Comment: the trace function has properties look at here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)